# How to improve speed for time limit exceeded

Tags: c++, c, performance

Is there any way to improve the running time for this program? I get time limit exceed error from the online judge, and it seems like my program is running slow?
So, this is the question for this program: http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

My code (language c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void FindPrime (int m, int n)
{
    int i, prime = 1;

    if (m <= n)
    {
        for (i = m - 1; i > 1; i--)
        {
            if (m % i == 0)
            {
                prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (prime == 1 && m != 1)
            printf ("%d\n", m);
        FindPrime (m + 1, n);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int num1, num2, i, cases;

    scanf ("%d", &cases);
    while (cases != 0)
    {
        scanf ("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
        FindPrime (num1, num2);
        printf ("\n");
        cases--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it is working but not optimized Code Review SE might be a more suitable site for this type of question.

Comment: Google "Sieve of Eratosthenes".

Comment: Googling "spoj prime generator solution" easily gives you the working code, but that would be the easy way out wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this question you need to learn *"Sieve of Eratosthenes"*.

1. First, get the idea of how it works from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_description). But, this is not enough to solve this question. Since, the complexity of the algorithm is O(n.log(log(n))). Therefore, if we put **n = 1000000000**. It will surely fail to execute.
2. Now, time to optimize it. Read it from [here](http://warp.povusers.org/programming/sieve_of_eratosthenes.html). But, we are done yet.
3. *(Please read this section after you are done with the above two)* Since we are to find the prime numbers is the range **[m,n]**. So, first create a list of prime numbers (let's call it **primeList**) between the range of 2 to 32000 using sieve of Eratosthenes (**sqrt(10^9) = 31622.7**, which is less then 32000). Now, check for every number **k** in the range of **[m,n]**

   3.1. If the number **k** is in the range of **2-32000**, and the number is in **primeList**.  Print it.

   3.2. If the number **k** > 32000, and is **not** divisible by all the numbers which are <= **sqrt(k)** and also in **primeList**. Print it. Else, ignore or don't print it. ( mind it **'1'** is not prime number).

You may check my [solution](http://www.codechef.com/viewplaintext/7204283). But, it is implemented slightly different than i explained although the concept applied is same.

Answer (score 0):

Your code it calculating/listing the prime numbers between to numbers m & n cases number of times. Now you algorithm takes O(n) time for each value of m & hence total time taken by your code for a single case is O(n x m) or O(n^2) times..So in total the time taken is cases * O(n^2).. This is bad..Use some better algorithm to ease the complexity..
Check this modified version of *Sieve of Eratosthenes*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE (int)(sizeof(boolean) / sizeof(int))
int main(){
  int up,low;
  int i,j;
  printf("\nEnter the upper limit: ");
  scanf("%d", &up);
  printf("\nEnter the lower limit: ");
  scanf("%d", &low);

  int boolean[up];
  int list[up];

  for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
  boolean[i] = 1;
  list[i] = 2 + i;
  }

  for(i = 0; i <= up; i++){
    if (boolean[i] == 1)
     for(j = i +1; j < SIZE; j++)
       if(list[j] % list[i] == 0)
       boolean[j] = 0; 

  }

  for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   if(boolean[i] == 1 && list[i] >= low && list[i] <= up)
   printf("%d ", list[i]);
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

This will not visit one number more than once & hence will reduce the complexity in logarithmic scale.